# gorm Selecting Specific Fields

Tags: go, grails-orm

I want to select like this; how can use one struct replace "in Select text"

```
    db.Table(model.TableName()).Select("ag_anchor.id,ag_anchor.name,ag_apply_record.id,ag_apply_record.name,ag_apply_record.id,ag_apply_record.price").Joins("left join ag_anchor anchor on anchor.id = ag_apply_record.anchor_id").Find(&data, "user_id = ?", userID)
```

I want to select like this; how can use one struct replace "in Select text"

Comment: Can you better detail the question? Provide a full code snippet with what you have and what you expect. However, it's hard to understand what's happening, thanks!

Comment: I want to use gorm query statements to formulate query result fields, but there are so many fields, can I use struct to replace them

Comment: Honestly, didn't get your question. What is the structure of your table? And the struct in which you're trying to put data? If you provide me more info I can build a small example for you, thanks